# How to find very large file copying status in java

Tags: java, file, copy, executorservice, monitor

I have requirement for monitoring the files copying status in a directory and the files are placed continuously into the directory in java. 
I am planing to use Executor framework to find out individual files copy status and I have written below code but it is not working as expected, file without copy completion I am getting notification as copying got completed.

```
private boolean isFileCopied(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);

    Scanner scanner;
    boolean isCopied = true;
    while (true) {
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            isCopied = false;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(filePath + " File is in copy State. ");
            sleepFile();
        }
        if (isCopied == false) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(filePath + "  copy completed");
    return isCopied;
}

   private static void sleepFile() {
    System.out.println("sleeping for 10 seconds");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please someone help me out how can I find the exact status of a file like file "copy in progress" or "copying done" and how can I monitor each and every file copying status If bunch of large files placed in a directory.

I have used watcher API but it is not solving my purpose. even the file without copying got completed I am getting notification as copying got completed. Below are my code changes.

### Using watcher service:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class FolderWatchDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Path outputWatchFolderPath =  Paths.get("/outputFolder/");
    final Path sourceFolderPath = Paths.get("/sourceFolder/");

    try {
        //Registering outputWatchFolderPath
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path dir = Paths.get(outputWatchFolderPath.toString());

        dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        System.out.println("Watch Service registered for dir: " + dir.getFileName());

        //copy files from inputfolder to o
        for (final Path path: Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceFolderPath))
            Files.copy(path, outputWatchFolderPath.resolve(path.getFileName()));

        while (true) {
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                 WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    System.out.println("file got created !!");
                }
                if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                    System.out.println("copying got completed !!");
                }
                if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    System.out.println("file deleted successfully !!");
                }
            }
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a `Scanner`? Why not just check `file.exists()`?

Comment: And also - why poll for the file when there is [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)?

Comment: I  have used watcher service also,even though file not yet copied I am just getting notification  as completed.  I am not getting accurate result with the watcher service really.

Comment: maybe you can try to first get the original file size then calculate the copied file size and compare them

Comment: Please show the code in which you use the `WatchService`.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have added watch service API code snippet in the first post. please review and let me If I am missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very elegant way to create a **Call Back** system and implementing it via implementing `ReadableByteChannel` in order to monitor the progerss of copying files. Also the benefit is there is no need to monitor a directory. You can explicitly monitor the progress of the file which is being copied.

The main idea is proposed by [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/IO_How_to/FileChannel/Monitor_progress_of_FileChannels_transferFrom_method.htm) site, but changed it a little to fit in your problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

interface ProgressCallBack {
    public void callback(CallbackByteChannel rbc, double progress);
}   

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProgressCallBack progressCallBack = new ProgressCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void callback(CallbackByteChannel rbc, double progress) {
                System.out.println(rbc.getReadSoFar());
                System.out.println(progress);
            }
        };

        try {
            copy("SOURCE FILE PATH", "DESTINATION FILE PATH", progressCallBack);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void copy(String source, String destination, ProgressCallBack callBack) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
        try {
            sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(new File(source)).getChannel();
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = new CallbackByteChannel(sourceChannel, Files.size(Paths.get(source)), callBack);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(sourceChannel.isOpen()){
                sourceChannel.close();
            }
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}

class CallbackByteChannel implements ReadableByteChannel {
    ProgressCallBack delegate;
    long size;
    ReadableByteChannel rbc;
    long sizeRead;

    CallbackByteChannel(ReadableByteChannel rbc, long expectedSize, ProgressCallBack delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.size = expectedSize;
        this.rbc = rbc;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        rbc.close();
    }

    public long getReadSoFar() {
        return sizeRead;
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return rbc.isOpen();
    }

    public int read(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {
        int n;
        double progress;
        if ((n = rbc.read(bb)) > 0) {
            sizeRead += n;
            progress = size > 0 ? (double) sizeRead / (double) size * 100.0 : -1.0;
            delegate.callback(this, progress);
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much STaefi, it worked.. but for my requirement is some external tool is going to copy the files to destination folder..I just need to observe the output folder files copying is completed or not..  ProgressCallBack progressCallBack = new ProgressCallBack() {
            @Override
            public int callback(CallbackByteChannel rbc, double progress) {
               return (int) progress;
            }
        };

Comment: If the progress is 100 then I am considering it as copied.. How can I achieve the same for just copying status as the copying is done by some external tool ??

Comment: What kind of external tools you have? Then your requirement about the monitoring the progress of copying a single file is changed now? Do you need to monitor a directory?

Comment: Yes STaefi, I need to monitor the directory, actually one of the external web application copies the large sized files continuously into our configured directory and We need to find the copy status of each file and if the copying is done successfully, need to process file for another business requirement.

Comment: At first your requirement brought the idea of monitoring (polling for) the changes of destination directory to my mind, too. After that I asked myself why I should monitor that directory? Then I thought about a system of firing some events after completing each copy separately. So you can call a method each time a copy reaches to 100%. You have this event (reaching to 100%) in your `ProgressCallBack` implementation. So you can even pass the name of the completed file to that method and use it there.

Comment: Are you using different codes for copying big files in the destination directory and the further businesses?

Comment: Yes STaefi, The copying done by different application into our configured directory and we need to find the copy status of each file whether the copying got completed or not.

Comment: I think the answer would be around the `WatchService` but as you can see in andy's answer it can handle only one copying thread at a time. So If we want to discuss about this new problem in this question both the question and the answer are going to be vague. It's better to leave this question and create a new question that you brief your problem of monitoring multiple copying thread in a directory using `WatchService` minimal sample code.

Comment: As you have mentioned, "So you can call a method each time a copy reaches to 100%. You have this event (reaching to 100%) in your ProgressCallBack implementation. So you can even pass the name of the completed file to that method and use it there", how it is possible as it is taking only the ReadableByteChannel implemented reference.

Comment: This was for when I was thinking that the `Copier` and the `Processor` programs are the same application which you are writing it's code. Now that you have a totally separated application that event raising is meaningless.

Comment: Can't we just watch the target folder for the progress of file copying?

Comment: can the java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel class will help this kind of requirement?

Comment: Watching a folder will be done by `WatchServer` as you know. You should just find a workaround to overcome the problem of concurrent file copying on that destination folder

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class FolderWatchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Path outputWatchFolderPath =  Paths.get("/outputFolder/");
        final Path sourceFolderPath = Paths.get("/sourceFolder/");

        try {
            // Registering outputWatchFolderPath
            WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Path dir = Paths.get(outputWatchFolderPath.toString());

            dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            System.out.println("Watch Service registered for dir: " + dir.getFileName());

                    // copy files from inputfolder to o
                        for (final Path path : Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceFolderPath))
                            Files.copy(path, outputWatchFolderPath.resolve(path.getFileName()),
                                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            String fileName = null;
            while (true) {
                WatchKey key;
                try {
                    key = watcher.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                    if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                        System.out.println("file got created !!" + ev.context());
                    }
                    if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                        String fName = ev.context().getFileName().toString();
                        if (fileName != null && !fName.equals(fileName)) {
                            System.out.println("file copying completed !!" + fileName);
                        }
                        fileName = fName;
                        System.out.println("copying " + fName);
                    }
                    if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                        System.out.println("file deleted successfully !!");
                    }
                }
                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: only works when there only one copying thread and no other modification in the target folder